# Both Image.export_to_png and Image.export_as_image not working

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        my_image = Image(source='test.png')
        with my_image.canvas:
            Triangle(point=(0, 0, 30, 30, 60, 0))
        my_image.export_to_png('test2.png')
        my_image.export_as_image().save('test3.png')
        return my_image

myapp = MyApp().run()
```

The expected outcome of its execution should be two copies of the 'test.png' named 'test2.png' and 'test3.png with the added triangle on them. However, two files with triangles only, without original texture are created. What is the mistake and how do I export widgets to png?

EDIT: I've done my research and found out that it is caused by the fact that these functions (I'm only sure about 
`image.export_to_png` but `image.export_as_image` provides the same result) export not the widget itself but rather canvas of the widget. That leads me to two question:

1)How do I export changed picture but not the changes themselves?

2)How do I just export the original image if no changes occurred?

Comment: What changes are you talking about? You can easily access the `source` attribute of `Image`, which is the original image.

Comment: I'm applying changes to the code (or I will, I just decided to try if importing works as I expect before I started coding and found that it doesn't), so I want to export png file with changes in it but not just the changes, I'm going to add some canvas to the MRE so I'm clearer.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Basically, I have a PNG picture of blank document, for which my program may auto-fill the blanks using data generated by user, or it may leave it blank.  I have "Export document into PNG" button which does what it says. I originally hoped to make due with only Image and Label widgets and get a PNG out of that, thus original wording of the question. But after some reading apparently I'm going to need canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just need to wait for the next frame, probably for OpenGL initialisation reasons:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Triangle
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.my_image = Image(source='test.png')
        with self.my_image.canvas:
            Triangle(point=(0, 0, 30, 30, 60, 0))

        Clock.schedule_once(self.export, 1)
        return self.my_image

    def export(self, dt):
        self.my_image.export_to_png('test2.png')
        self.my_image.export_as_image().save('test3.png')


myapp = MyApp().run()
```

> EDIT: I've done my research and found out that it is caused by the fact that these functions (I'm only sure about image.export_to_png but image.export_as_image provides the same result) export not the widget itself but rather canvas of the widget.

There isn't anything to the widget's appearance *except* what it draws on its canvas.

I don't understand your final questions.

Comment: Seems to work.

My final questions were related for when I don't wait for the next frame in which case only widget's canvas was imported but not the widget itself :-) 

Also, I'm gonna run into it sometime soon anyway... I don't know if this is a topic for huge completely different question but do you know if it is possible to import widget with its original texture size and not with window's original size?

Comment: The `export_as_image().save()` will produce the same result as `export_to_png()`, because `export_to_png()` is defined as `export_as_image().save()`.

Comment: @LevBarenboim You have misunderstood the problem, there is no such thing as "widget's canvas was imported but not the widget itself". Your problem is that the widget hadn't drawn its source image yet, not that it wasn't included in the output. Also, the output _does_ have the widget's original texture size.

Comment: @inclement Sorry, I'm not very good with depths of kivy yet... And for "the output does have the widget's original texture size."... My original file is 1500x3000 but it gets lowered to 800x600 when imported, as my window's size in MRE and even less at my actual app, as I'm importing from 'Review / Approve Changes' page. So my question was about that

Comment: `export_to_png` saves the widget with size and position as it appears in your application, no you can't easily have the output depend on the original image. You could read the export_to_png source though and have it scale the output to achieve any output resolution up to the gpu texture size limit.

Comment: @inclement Thank you for your help!