# How to access raw image data in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-imaging-library

How to access raw image data of a `kivy.core.image.Image` object? The docs say that the `image` property of the `Image` object has the raw data of the image, but when I print it, it returns `None`:

This is what I did:

```py
#paintwg is the widget

img = paintwg.export_to_image()
print(img.image)

Output:
>>> None
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`kivy.uix.widget.Widget.export_as_image`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.export_as_image):

> Return an core [Image](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.Image) of the actual widget.

From [`kivy.core.image`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html):

> Core classes for loading images and converting them to a [Texture](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#kivy.graphics.texture.Texture). The raw image data can be keep in memory for further access.

The latter might relate to the kwarg `keep_data`. From the constructor [`kivy.core.image.Image(arg, **kwargs)`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.Image):

> *arg*: can be a string (str), Texture, BytesIO or Image object

Let's check these four possibilitìes:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.image import Image as Core_Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from PIL import Image as PILImage
from io import BytesIO


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        img_path = 'path/to/your/image.png'

        # From string path
        img = Core_Image(img_path)
        print(img.image)    # <kivy.core.image.img_sdl2.ImageLoaderSDL2 object at ...

        # From Texture object
        img = Core_Image(img.texture)
        print(img.image)    # None

        # From BytesIO object
        pil_img = PILImage.open(img_path)
        img_bytes = BytesIO()
        pil_img.save(img_bytes, format='PNG')
        img_bytes.seek(0)
        img = Core_Image(BytesIO(img_bytes.read()), ext='png')
        print(img.image)    # <kivy.core.image.img_sdl2.ImageLoaderSDL2 object at ...

        # From existing image object
        img = Core_Image(img_path)
        img = Core_Image(img)
        print(img.image)    # <kivy.core.image.img_sdl2.ImageLoaderSDL2 object at ...


myapp = MyApp().run()
```

Even setting the kwarg `keep_data=True` doesn't store anything in the `image` property when using some Texture object as source.

Now – guess what! – how does [`export_as_image`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/d0e20d744e53bdd17d4d85fd64772c2be092d319/kivy/uix/widget.py#L730) generate the image object? Correct:

```py
img = Image(fbo.texture)
```

So, re-reading the second link, we know, that everything is stored in the corresponding `texture` property! Let's see (code taken from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62435605/11089932)):

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.my_image = Image(source='path/to/your/image.png')
        Clock.schedule_once(self.export, 1)
        return self.my_image

    def export(self, dt):
        img = self.my_image.export_as_image()
        print(img.image)    # None
        print(img.texture)  # <Texture ... size=(800, 600) colorfmt='rgba' ...


myapp = MyApp().run()
```

In the `pixels` property of the Texture object, the raw data is stored. If you want to have that somehow "readable", e.g. using some Pillow `Image` object, you'd need to convert:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from PIL import Image as PILImage


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.my_image = Image(source='path/to/your/image.png')
        Clock.schedule_once(self.export, 1)
        return self.my_image

    def export(self, dt):
        img = self.my_image.export_as_image()
        pil_img = PILImage.frombytes('RGBA',
                                     img.texture.size,
                                     img.texture.pixels)
        print(pil_img)    # <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=800x600 at ...


myapp = MyApp().run()
```

Now, you should be able to access single pixel values from the result of `export_as_image` during runtime!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
kivy:          2.0.0
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Aah, I understand now. Thanks for the help!